# Customizing enumerate list with item label as parameter of new environment

Tags: environments, enumerate, parameters

I want to define a `new environment` which would allow me to have a like-`enumerate list`, i.e. have the `\item`s numbered like in an `enumerate` environment and change the `item` name by the one given as parameter. The `environement` would be `indent`ed automatically to align itself with the other lists. Something like this:

```
aaa 1 - text here

aaa 2 - texte here
```

I have tried different things but could not find the right match. The package `enumerate` introduces errors in my whole document.

Comment: Please post the minimal code of what you have. This saves us typing a lot of code for you and makes debugging much easier. Maybe we will spot a little mistake and all errors disappear with this fixed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `enumitem`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1]
  \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*,label=aaa \arabic* --]
    \item \lipsum[1]
    \item Some other text
  \end{enumerate}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]